# Dotnet project conversion try-convert fails when "Multiple installs of MSBuild"

Tags: c#, .net

```
try-convert -w Test.csproj --target-framework netstandard2.0
```

results in:

```
Multiple installs of MSBuild detected please select one:

...
Instance 6
    Name: .NET Core SDK
    Version: 3.0.100
    MSBuild Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview7-012821\
```

But specifying one of those paths

```
try-convert -w Test.csproj --target-framework netstandard2.0 -m "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview7-012821\"
```

results in :

#### Exceptions

```
System.ArgumentException: Directory "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview7-012821"" does not exist (Parameter 'msbuildSearchPaths')
A directory or directories in "msbuildSearchPaths" do not exist
```

Comment: Hi @ozBob, did you find any relevant answer for your question. I am also struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing slash from the MSBuild path:

```
try-convert -w Test.csproj --target-framework netstandard2.0 -m "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview7-012821"
```

Comment: I tried the same but could not find helpful. Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68723428/while-doing-migration-wpf-net-framework-application-to-net5-getting-multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I had the same problem. When I used "try-convert" it requested to choose a instance of .NET, but I couldn't type anything. When I tried to use "--target-framework" it didn't help me, but "-m" works great.

```
try-convert -w "Test.csproj" -m "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400"
```

You can use "--no-backup" if your code was published in source control (git, svn and etc).