# Multiple instance issue - .NET framework 4.8 WPF application to .NET5

Tags: .net-5, .net-framework-version

When I am trying to convert my WPF application to .NET 5. I am getting the following below.

Can someone guide me please?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>try-convert -p "D:\ClientNew\Routines\Routines.csproj"
Multiple installs of MSBuild detected please select one:
Instance 1
    Name: .NET Core SDK
    Version: 5.0.302
    MSBuild Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.302\
Instance 2
    Name: .NET Core SDK
    Version: 2.1.524
    MSBuild Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.524\
Instance 3
    Name: .NET Core SDK
    Version: 2.1.202
    MSBuild Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.202\
```

I also followed [Multiple installs of MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160126/dotnet-project-conversion-try-convert-fails-when-multiple-installs-of-msbuild) but not much of help.

```
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>try-convert -w Routines.csproj --target-framework
> net5.0 -m "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.302"
> System.AggregateException: A directory or directories in
> "msbuildSearchPaths" do not exist (Directory "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.302"" does not exist (Parameter
> 'msbuildSearchPaths'))  ---> System.ArgumentException: Directory
> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.302"" does not exist (Parameter
> 'msbuildSearchPaths')    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   
> at Microsoft.Build.Locator.MSBuildLocator.RegisterMSBuildPath(String[]
> msbuildSearchPaths)    at
> Microsoft.Build.Locator.MSBuildLocator.RegisterMSBuildPath(String
> msbuildPath)    at
> MSBuild.Abstractions.MSBuildHelpers.HookAssemblyResolveForMSBuild(String
> msbuildPath) in /_/src/MSBuild.Abstractions/MSBuildHelpers.cs:line 405
> at MSBuild.Conversion.Program.Run(String project, String workspace,
> String msbuildPath, String tfm, Boolean forceWebConversion, Boolean
> preview, Boolean diffOnly, Boolean noBackup, Boolean keepCurrentTfms,
> Boolean update, Boolean mauiConversion) in
> /_/src/try-convert/Program.cs:line 93
```

I also installed `upgrade-assistant` and now trying to use this command. I am getting `Required command was not provided` error:

```
C:\Users\rya\Test>upgrade-assistant C:\Users\rya\Test\Client\Screen.sln
Required command was not provided.
Unrecognized command or argument 'C:\Users\rya\Test\Client\Screen.sln'
```

Comment: Did you run `try-convert` using Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt? If you use this, it is not compatible with try-convert at all. Please use normal Command Prompt.

Comment: Hi @EriawanKusumawardhono, I am running normal command prompt. I even tried upgrade-assistant tool but that is complaining about `Required command was not provided.`. If you any proper solution, can you please provide me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though this is because the conversion tool is wanting to know which version of MSBuild to use.

This question: [Dotnet project conversion try-convert fails when "Multiple installs of MSBuild"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160126/dotnet-project-conversion-try-convert-fails-when-multiple-installs-of-msbuild) has some information on it about how to indicate which version the tool should use, although it doesn't have an accepted answer as yet.

Comment: I have included my findings in my question. Can you please help with it. Thanks